# C# ListView: how to hide images when using View.Details

Tags: c#, listview

When I add a SmallImageList and a LargeImageList, images are also displayed in the View.Details view. I only need images for View.SmallIcon and View.LargeIcon. How can I prevent displaying images for View.Details?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the `xxxImageList` properties where you change the `View` property. Example: `listView1.SmallImageList = listView1.View == View.SmallIcon ? yourSmallImageList : null;`.